# AFNetworking vs SDWebimage

Tags: afnetworking, nsurlsession, sdwebimage

I am developing a news app. Get the image and news from the server. I want to use cache to get the old news. And the custom can remove the cache when there is less disk storage.

The NSURLSession seems have bug for cache. So I decided to use AFNetworking or SDWebImage. But I don't know which one is suit for my app.

Comment: Use the DFImageManager instead of AFNetworing and SDWebimage?

Comment: @kean Can you elaborate on the advantage of DFImageManager over SDWebimage? I am looking the same thing but considering Haneke+AFNetworking since some other library rely on AF.

Comment: @kean Just checked the github wiki and your DFImageManager looks pretty neat. Quick question: what is the best way to integrate DFImageManager into a project with existing AFNetworking pod?

Answer (score 0):

SDWebImage is very convenient especially with the progressive image download. But it’s based out of **NSURLConnection** ( even in the latest version 3.7.5 ) and we know that that is deprecated starting iOS 9. NSURLSession has been around for 3+ years now. Surprisingly SDWebImage has still not migrated to NSURLSession.

See the SDWebImage: [[Discussion] Migration to NSURLSessions](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/1291).

**AFNetworking 3.0** is completely based on NSURLSession. So I think AfNetworking would a better choice than SDWebImage.